# Rustlang book 14.3 - error[E0425]: cannot find function `add_one` in crate `add_one`

Tags: rust

I'm working through the official Rustlang book and have reached chapter [14.3](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch14-03-cargo-workspaces.html). However, once I reach a certain point of building the *workspace*, the compiler throws an error. My project looks like this (as per the book)

```
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── add-one
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── lib.rs
├── adder
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── main.rs
└── target
```

with `Cargo.toml`

```
[workspace]

members = [
    "adder",
    "add-one",
]
```

`add-one/src/lib.rs`

```
#![allow(unused)]
fn main() {
pub fn add_one(x: i32) -> i32 {
    x + 1
}
}
```

`adder/Cargo.toml`

```
...
[dependencies]

add-one = { path = "../add-one" }
```

`adder/src/main.rs`

```
use add_one;

fn main() {
    let num = 10;
    println!(
        "Hello, world! {} plus one is {}!",
        num,
        add_one::add_one(num)
    );
}
```

I initially tried typing the files out, but got the above error, so decided to copy/paste all the files from the book, but no luck there either. What am I missing? Is there a problem with my code, or is the example in the book faulty?

Comment: `add_one` is defined inside the body of `main` and isn't visible outside of it.

Comment: thank you @IvanC, it worked to just remove the `fn main() {` and closing `}` lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are defining `add_one` inside the `main` function:

```rust
#![allow(unused)]
fn main() {
    pub fn add_one(x: i32) -> i32 {
        x + 1
    }
}
```

Nested functions are limited in scope to their parent, meaning that `add_one` is not visible outside of the `main`. You can fix this by declaring `add_one` in *module scope*:

```rust
pub fn add_one(x: i32) -> i32 {
    x + 1
}
```